# Delete shared contact folders from Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am the sysadmin for a company of about 100 users.  We run Exchange through Office 365 and Outlook 2013.  As part of my normal day to day routine I use Outlook to access other users contacts folders in order to import/export/copy contacts.  When I do that I use Outlook and go to File > Open > Other Users Folder.  This causes their contacts to show up under 'My Contacts' on the Outlook 2013 'People' page (see screenshot below):

[image: contacts]

The first two contacts in the screenshot above are mine, most of the remaining items are not.  You can see that next to most of those contacts there is someone's name, referencing that the contact list is stored in their mailbox.

Because of this, it's difficult for me to manage my own contacts because I see contacts from all of these other users and I don't want to.  My question is how can I remove all of these extra contact directories from my Outlook so I no longer see other users contacts when I click the 'To:' button on an e-mail, or search my Lync contacts list.

I've tried right-clicking on the shared contacts, but there's no option to remove or delete so I'm not sure how to proceed.  Google has also not turned up much in the way of helpful results.

Comment: Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is due to your 365 account having full access to the above users' mailboxes. When a user has full access to a mailbox, it automatically maps the mailbox to their Outlook.

There are several ways to get around this, but the easiest would be to remove and readd permissions using remote PowerShell.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646504/en-us